# Rubymine debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I'm using Rubymine v2023 3.2.2

When I click on the debugger icon, it starts to debug but doesn't stop at the breakpoints but keeps running the full code.

I tried to restart my pc, uninstall rubymine and ruby, and reinstall both. I have the latest version of rubymine and ruby.

Comment: Could you please specify whether you're working with a local or remote Ruby SDK? In addition, it'd be great if you provide a code sample where the problem occurs. Does it happen in some simple Ruby scripts with several lines?

Comment: If you use SimpleCov then disabling it may make it worked.